# Unable to understand the regex expression for 2-5 Letter Palindrome?

Tags: regex

I'm new to Regular expressions.I'm trying to understand the code that explains about palindrome.Below posted is the expression

```
\\b(\\w)?(\\w)\\w?\\2\\1
```

This Expression is matching

```
my "dad" "sees" a "kayak" at "noon"
```

I kind of getting an intuition..like

```
\\b -ensures that you are at the beginning of the sentence.

\\w -ensures that it is a word character and it is captured into group1
     ? does it make (\\w) optional ..because i read some where that if you 
     put '?' in front of a token,it makes the token optional ex:https? will   
     match "http" as well
\\2 - for matching the second group
\\1 -  for matching the first..

  what bothers me is "(\\w)\\w?" which is making me difficult to understand 
  the expression.Any help will be appreciated.
```

Comment: Btw, just to be clear, your regex is: `\b(\w)?(\w)\w?\2\1`. The extra backslashes are only part of whatever language you are embedding the regex in - probably Java.

Comment: @SteveBennett: It doesn't work for 2 and 3 letter palindrome in Java. Only in JavaScript. If the first `?` is moved inside the capturing group. It would work in Java. This is due to the fact that `\1` in JavaScript matches empty string if nothing is captured, while Java (and many other flavors) always fail in such case.

Comment: Oh, this is javascript? In that case, you can make life simpler by expressing the regex inside forward slashes: `/\b(\w)?(\w)\w?\2\1/` - not that this helps your problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

A palindrome can have either an even or an odd number of letters.  When it's even, like "noon", all letters in the first half are repeated.  The optional `\\w?` without parenthesis is for the odd case, where the middle letter is not repeated.  I.e. with "kayak" the y is not repeated, so it doesn't need to be backreferenced later.

Answer (score 0):

The regex above only works in JavaScript as advertised (2-5 character palindrome *prefix*).
In Java, Ruby, Python, PCRE, Perl (and probably many other flavors), the regex only matches 4-5 character palindrome prefix.

The regex works in JavaScript, since backreference in JavaScript matches an empty string if the corresponding capturing group does not match anything (undefined/null), instead of failing the match like in the case of most flavors.

Given the string `aba`, in JavaScript:

- `(\w)?` matches empty string. Capturing group 1 is undefined, since we are taking the branch without `(\w)`.
- `(\w)` matches the first `a` and sets capturing group 2 to `a`
- `\w?` matches `b`
- `\2` references capturing group 2 and matches `a`
- `\1` matches empty string, as capturing group 1 is undefined.

Other engines simply fails at the last step, since backreference in those flavors fails the match when the corresponding capturing group is undefined/null.

In order to make the regex works for 2-5 character palindrome prefix in any engine listed above, you only need to make a slight change:

```
\b(\w?)(\w)\w?\2\1
     ^
```

By putting the optional quantifier inside, the capturing group 1 always capture *something* (can be a word character or empty string, but not undefined/null).

Given the input `aba`, the first capturing group now captures an empty string, so `\1` matches an empty string and the match succeeds on any engine listed above.

Comment: Currently, ideone and regexplanet shows strange result for this regex on Perl. It's probably a bug. Here is the link to my gist showing the different results on different versions of Perl: https://gist.github.com/nhahtdh/8f5d3c73661c3075e132